# android: Is it possible to detect the app was banned on Google Play Market?

Tags: android, google-play

So I need to detect in app if it was banned by Google no matter why. Just to inform the user about that (and that there will be no updates or whatever). So is there a way to detect the ban?
I'm pretty sure my app doesn't have any violation but like Carl said:
I afraid my app might get banned/suspended occasionally or eventually and Google typically does not warn about that. The reason is that Google is deliberately sudden and vague about enforcing its policies and this can result in innocent devs getting smacked unexpectedly.
And I know that this happens already and I know about such developers, they are usually small independent devs. Also I know that Google's support usually doesn't even answer emails about that fact. Moreover if you gonna try to discuss their decision about suspending your app on market this could result in permanent ban without any further details.

Comment: Sounds like you suspect your app might get suspended, and as Google typically does not warn about that it suggests you might have an idea yourself that something is borderline in the app.  It seems that Google is deliberately sudden and vague about enforcing its policies - perhaps because revealing its criteria more specifically could assist those who would like to game them.  This can result in innocent devs getting smacked unexpectedly.  Best to correct anything you suspect might be amiss before a suspension occurs.

Comment: Like you said, "Google is deliberately sudden and vague about enforcing its policies" and "This can result in innocent devs getting smacked unexpectedly" so I'm afraid of become such innocent dev due to Google's politics. That's why Im asking my question since "Google typically does not warn about that".

Comment: You've quoted me somewhat out of context, actually inadvertently attributing some of your own concerns to me, in both your edited post and in the comment above, so you might want to just refer to my comment without paraphrasing as this is a sensitive topic. I understand now that you are being pro-active and don't have a specific reason to suspect that your own app would be suspended. There is a saying that one should expect the best but prepare for the worst, but I would add that one should not spend too much time on the latter.

Answer (score 1):

If app has Internet permission it can just bring up the app's listing page on the GP store.  If not there - and if you have ability to access similar pages -then you might *infer* that the app was taken down.

Comment: Are you trying to say that if I generate market url for my app and make HTTP request to that url that will result a 404? I'm not sure about that... And surely I can't simulate this scenario to test it... I'm looking for proper resolve for ban situation if there is some.

Comment: Well, you might have to scrape the returned page for something you have in your description. Just a thought - I'm not saying it will work out for you, and certainly haven't tried it myself.  Better to just try to stay compliant as an app knowing it got suspended is of very limited utility.